# openGL shaders errors

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to understand OpenGL shaders.
I'm working on windows and my OpenGL version is 3.0.
I have a file that should draw a triangle and change its color every 3 seconds but when I debug I get a warning (see in the pic below) and I can see only a triangle that doesn't change its color. I followed the guide from [this](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) website:
Source code is [here](http://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/shaders-uniform).

I changed shaders version to 130 according with the best answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407774/get-supported-glsl-versions) question, but I keep getting this warning.

Here it is a screenshot of my error:

[image]

Comment: did you change these lines `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);`
`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);` in the source code?

Comment: @GnimucKey No I didn't change them, what should I change in these lines?

Comment: Layout qualifiers are not supported in 130.

Comment: @GreenMamba `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);` should be `0` cause your OpenGL version is 3.`0`.

Comment: i highly recommend you to upgrade your graphic card in order to learn `Modern GL`. after changing the minor version to 0, you may need to comment the following line `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`, and next, you need to adjust your shader code...

Comment: If you're going to recommend an upgrade for something more modern, shouldn't he go outside and climb trees or something, and wait for Vulkan?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I solved it. I changed the graphic card (I was using the integrated graphic card) and I installed the latest driver and the warnings disappeared following instructions.

Comment: @Robinson no, you may misunderstood me. the tutorials that OP is using says `...This is also the reason why our tutorials are geared at Core-Profile OpenGL version 3.3. ...`,  i should write `in order to meet the demand of that tutorial`. sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

The `location` layout qualifier is only supported in GLSL 3.30 and later. So the version you need to specify at the start of your shader code to use this feature is:

```
#version 330
```

Also, you tried to use:

```
#version 130 core
```

This is not a valid version. The profile part of the version definition was only introduced in GLSL 1.50.